# Should I set hasStableIds to true every time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have [read](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged) that, setting `hasStableIds` to true, and overriding `getItemId` will improve performance of recyclerView when `notifyDatasetChanged` calls. But for its sibling methods (`notifyItemInserted` etc..), they haven't mentioned anywhere about stableIds. So does it improve other methods performance too? If I am not invoking `notifyDatasetChanged` ever, and only notify through other more specific calls, should I bother overriding `getItemId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does provide small optimization for layout manager - namely it allows internal [`RecyclerView.Recycler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler) to identify viewholders in the scrap heap and reuse them without rebinding during layout pass.

However its hard to notice that it ever happens aside from when `notifyDatasetChanged` is called as scrapped views that don't get laid out are usually recycled at the end of layout phase anyway.

Generally if your items have int / long IDs already there's no harm in using it but you really don't lose much by omitting it.