# Android Recyclerview StableIDs when Replacing Entire List

Tags: android, performance, arraylist, android-recyclerview, ids

According to Android documentation:

> Enabling Stable IDs will make the recyclerview do less work when
> updating the list. Even if we call the notifyDataSetChanged(), it does
> not have to handle the complete re-ordering of the whole adapter
> because it can find if the item at a position is the same as before,
> which results in faster performance of the recyclerview.

It also states that I should prefer `notifyOnItemChanged(), notifyOnItemRemoved(), notifyOnItemInseted() etc.` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()` and prompts me to use it as last resort.

However, what happens if I simply want a recyclerview that doesn't support operations such as add/remove/replace at position and It is designed to replace the entire list at once? For example, I might want to display either **Popular** or **Top Rated** movies, which means that the entire content in the recyclerview will be changed. In this case, is it faster to simply:

```
setHasStableIDs(False);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Optimization is minuscule, in your example if stable IDs were enabled and there'd be a movie that was both popular and top rated at the same time it would allow `notifyDataSetChanged()` to "carry over" `ViewHolder` representing that item without re-binding it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138347/should-i-set-hasstableids-to-true-every-time/67141419#67141419

Comment: So, no optimization can be done in my example?

Comment: No, if anything for your use case I'd recommend not using stable IDs because recyclerview layout managers have tendency to "stick" to top item and (I'm not 100% certain but pretty sure) that would cause odd behavior like leaving your list half-scrolled if there was an ID hit for first visible position.